# How to write a divisor: Exercise n 20 pag 285 from Geometry of algebraic curves by Arbarello, Cornalba, Griffiths, Harris

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, projective-geometry

Let $C$ a complex Riemann surface (compact) and $\alpha:C^{'} \rightarrow C$ an unramified double cover of $C$.
Define the application $\alpha_{*} :Div(C^{'}) \rightarrow Div(C)$ as follow $$\forall E\in Div(C^{'}), E=\sum_{i=1}^{n}q_i \Rightarrow \alpha_{*}(E)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha(q_i) .$$
(then we can extend the application to all divisor using linearity)
Now suppose that $E \in Div(C^{'})$ is a divisor  such that $\alpha_{*}(E)$ is equivalent to the zero divisor, i.e $\alpha_{*}(E) \equiv 0$ where the relation of equivalence is the classical relation defined on divisor (i.e. $D,D^{'} \in Div(C^{'})$ are equivamente if and only if $D-D^{'}=(f)$ with $f$ a meromorphic function on $C^{'}$).
Put $\tau: C^{'} \rightarrow C^{'}$ the involution sheet exchange.
Then find a divisor $D\in Div(C^{'})$ such that $E \equiv D- \tau D$.
Such divisor is involved in the characterization of the Weil pairing.
Hint from book: due to theory we know that the norm map $Nm_{\alpha}:M^{*}(C^{'})\rightarrow M^{*}(C)$ is surjective. So using the hypothesis, $\alpha_{*}(E)=(f)$ where $f$ is a meromorphic funtion on $C$, we get: $\alpha_{*}(E)=Nm_{\alpha}(g)$ with $g$ a meromorphic funtion on $C^{'}$.
  Put $D=E+(g)$. Why is this the divisor that satisfy $E\equiv D- \tau D$?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions or comments.

Comment: Sorry but in my comment i said that the coefficients of $\alpha_{*}(D)$ are even. Why do you say in your edit that it's always the case.....?

Comment: I don't understand why does the coefficent of $\alpha_{*}(E)$ is always even?

Comment: can you post a new answer with the complete proof?

Answer (score 3):

Do this: Let $P\in C$ be a point that appears in the support of $\alpha_*E$ with coefficient $a$ and let $P_1,P_2=\tau(P_1)\in C'$ be the points that map to $P$ with coefficients $a_1$ and $a_2$ in $E$. Observe that since $a_1+a_2=a$, $-\tau\left((a_1-\frac a2)P_1\right)=(a_2-\frac a2)P_2$, which means that $E-\alpha^*\left(\frac a2P\right)$ can be written as desired near $P_1$ and $P_2$. Doing this for all $P\in C$ means that there is a $D$ such that
$$
E-\alpha^*\left(\frac 12\alpha_*E\right) \equiv D -\tau D
$$
In other words, this gives you what you want if $\alpha_*E$ is linearly equivalent to a divisor with only even coefficients.

**EDIT:** According to *dario*'s comment+answer this is always the case.

Comment: In your proof you have to use the coefficent $\frac{a}{2}$ but you are not sure that is even.

Comment: Soory. It is just to be clear. You write $E-\alpha^{*} \left( \frac{1}{2} \alpha_{*} E \right) \equiv D- \tau D$. Does this relation implies $E \equiv D-\tau D$?

Comment: i've found this relations: 1) if a is the coefficent of the point $p \in supp(\alpha_{*}(E))$ then we get $a=a_1 + a_2$ where $a_i$ is the order of the point $q_i \in \pi^{-1}(p)$ of the funtion $g$.   2) if we put $D=E+(g)$ then using the fact that $\alpha_{*}(D)=\alpha_{*}(E)+\alpha_{*}(g)$ , with $\alpha_{*}(E)=(Nm_{\pi}(g))$, where $Nm_{\pi}$ is the norm function, and the fact that $\alpha_{*}(g)=(Nm_{\pi}(g))$ we get $\alpha_{*}(D)=2(Nm_{\pi}(g))$

Comment: dario: 1) Yes, I said that this works if $a$ is even. 2) You assumed that $\alpha_*E$ is trivial and hence $\equiv 0$ 3) I'm not convinced by your norm calculation.

Comment: Can you expain the relation at the beginning of the third line of your answer? I don't understand Why at the left part of the equation there is $a_{2}$.

Comment: From the excercise the relation seams to be true for every divisor E that satisfy the hipothesis. In fact in the book the author uses this relation not saing anything about the case that you think it isn't possibile. This is only to give a comment about the second case. If i use the divisor suggested in the proof $D=E+(g)$ is there a way to compute directly $D-\tau D$ ?

Comment: there is no $a_2$ on the left part. Which equation are you looking at? // Maybe it is true and maybe your norm calculation is OK, I'm just saying that you are stating facts based on some mystery book.

Comment: Ok we will say that it will be correct when we will have some proof. I'm looking at $- \tau (a_{1}-\frac{a}{2})P_{1}=....$

Comment: so where is $a_2$ in that?

Comment: $−\tau((a_1−a/2)P1)=(a_2−a/2)P2$

Comment: that's the right side. :) What exactly is your question? $\tau$ swaps the points $P_1$ and $P_2$, so this equality follows from the previous one.

Comment: I've just realized that I did not specify what $a_i$ were. I guess I thought it was obvious, sorry. I edited the answer now. Was that the issue?

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, the definition of $a_1$ and $a_2$ makes no difference. If $a_1+a_2=a$, then $-\tau\left((a_1-\frac a2)P_1\right)=(a_2-\frac a2)P_2$ holds regardless, so this could not have been the problem. But then (again): with what exactly are you having a problem?

Comment: now it's ok. I'm studing the remaining case

Comment: If you care to explain that argument regarding the norm we can see whether it works. You could post it as another answer with some more details... Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comment. WHAT I SAID ABOUT THE NORM.

Let $D=E+(g)$ where $g$ is the meromorphic funcion determined in the question. The application $\alpha_{*}$ is linear so if we compute:

$$\alpha_{*}(D)=\alpha_{*}(E)+ \alpha_{*}(g),$$
using the hypothesis we know that $\alpha{*}(E)= \left( Nm_{\pi}(g) \right)$ where in the map $Nm_{\pi}$ is defined as: $$ \forall p \in C :Nm_{\pi}(g)(p)= \prod_{q \in\pi^{-1}(p)}g(q)^{\nu(q)},$$ and $\nu(q)$ is the moltiplicity of $q$ in the fiber of $\pi$.

Due to the fact that $\pi$ is unramified double cover we get: $$ \forall p \in C: Nm_{\pi}(g)(p)=g(q_1)g(q_2)$$, setting ${q_1,q_2}\in \pi^{-1}(p)$.
We can check that $\alpha_{*}(g)= \left( Nm_{\pi}(g) \right)$. So using this fact we get:
$$\alpha_{*}(D)=\alpha_{*}(E)+ \alpha_{*}(g)=\alpha_{*}(Nm_{\pi}(g))+\alpha_{*}(Nm_{\pi}(g))=2\alpha_{*}(Nm_{\pi}(g)).$$
I don't know if this is usefull for our problem.

Comment: OK, I think this indeed does it.